# why doesn't this overloading function signature work?

Tags: typescript

When I tried to declare overloading function type with full type signature, typescript throw an error.

for example:

```js
// functions full type signature
type CreateElement = {
    (tag : 'a') : HTMLAnchorElement,
    (tag : 'canvas') : HTMLCanvasElement,
    (tag : 'table') : HTMLTableElement,
    (tag:string) : HTMLElement
}


// functions implementation
let createElement:CreateElement = (tag:string):HTMLElement => {
    return document.createElement(tag)
}


/* error : 
Type '(tag: string) => HTMLElement' is not assignable to type 'CreateElement'.
  Type 'HTMLElement' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLAnchorElement': charset, coords, download, hreflang, and 21 more
*/
```

but it works:

```js
function createElement(tag:'a'):HTMLAnchorElement
function createElement(tag:'canvas'):HTMLCanvasElement
function createElement(tag:'table'):HTMLTableElement
function createElement(tag:string):HTMLElement
function createElement(tag:string) {
    return document.createElement(tag)
}
```

Comment: Because the function you are trying to assign to the variable doesn't have those overloads?

Comment: Function statements support a loose checking of overloads that function expressions don't. You could consider it a missing feature for function expressions, as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#47769](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47669). Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since the output type of createElement function depends on its input type parameters, we should use generic type instead of concrete type.

we should implement it in two way:

```js
function createElement<T extends keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap>
(tag: T, options?:ElementCreationOptions): HTMLElementTagNameMap[T] {
    return document.createElement(tag, options)
}
```

OR:

```js
type CreateElement<T extends HTMLElement = HTMLElement> = {
    <R extends string>(tag:R, options?:{}):T
}



let createElement:CreateElement = (tag:string, options?:{}) => {
    return document.createElement(tag, options)
}


createElement('a')
createElement('canvas')
```